# properties of distributions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

If $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f dx = 1$$, with $f > 0 \forall x$, then prove or disprove: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + f} dx $$ diverges.
The hint I got is to consider the measure of the set$(x:f > 1)$. May be the measure is zero thereby ensuring the divergence of integral?

Comment: An example was given of $f(x) = 1$ on $(0,1)$ and zero elsewwhere. That proves that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+f(f)}dx$ does not always diverge.  Can you prove that it always converges?

Comment: @Mark Fischler I think it diverges a.e.

Comment: @MarkFischler But then the required integral is $\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{2} dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 1dx + \int_{0}^\infty 1 dx $ which is divergent!

Comment: Oops, that example is wrong, it does diverge.

Comment: Do you also mean that $f\geq 0$?

Comment: thanks to all, I added the additional hypothesis of non negativity so much required for the solutions.

Comment: It's shocking nobody mentioned the easy proof suggested in the OP.

Comment: @Hurkyl: In our defense, OP had a typo earlier stating $(x: f>0)$ for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I assume two things: $\int |f|<\infty$ and $f>-1$ a.e.

\begin{aligned} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+f} dx & \geq \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+|f|} dx \\ & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1-1+\frac{1}{1+|f|} dx \\
 & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1-\frac{|f|}{1+|f|} dx \\
& \geq \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1-|f| dx \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 1 - \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f| \\
& = \infty.
\end{aligned}

Comment: so then the non negativity is non-essential?

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes, I didn't use non-negativity here. The only assumption I used was absolute integrability of $f$.

Comment: this assumes that $f> -1$, as $\frac{1}{1+f}$ is negative when $f<-1$

Comment: @clark You're right, I should include that. Still stronger than the nonnegativity assumption. I also think that can probably be relaxed by splitting up the space depending on whether $\frac{1}{1+f}>-1$.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose that $f$ is nonnegative (you say it's a distribution?). Notice that $1=\frac{1}{1+f}+\frac{f}{1+f}$. Also $0\leq \frac{f}{1+f}\leq f$ which means $\frac{f}{1+f}$ is integrable. Since the l.h.s. is not integrable, it follows that $\frac{1}{1+f}$ is not integrable.

Comment: good and easy answer!

Answer (score 4):

If $$ \int _{-\infty }^{\infty}\frac{1}{f+1} d x < \infty$$

Then $$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty}\frac{1/4}{f+1} d x +\int _{-\infty }^{\infty}f d x < \infty$$

But
\begin{align*}
\int _{-\infty }^{\infty}\frac{1/4}{f+1} d x +\int _{-\infty }^{\infty}f d x&=
\int _{-\infty }^{\infty}\frac{1/4}{f+1}+f d x\\
&=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty}\frac{f^2+ f+1/4 }{f+1} d x \\
&=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty}\frac{(f+1/2)^2}{f+1} d x \\
&\geq \int _{-\infty }^{\infty}\frac{(f/2+1/2)^2}{f+1} d x\,\,\text{ since } f\geq 0\\
&\geq 1/4\int _{-\infty }^{\infty}\frac{(f+1)^2}{f+1}f d x \\
&\geq 1/4\int _{-\infty }^{\infty}f+1d x \\
&>\infty
\end{align*}

A contradiction

Answer (score 4):

An obvious thing to do with the hint is observe that $f > 1$ is the same thing as $\frac{1}{1+f} < \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that:

$$\int_{-N}^{N} \frac{1}{f(x)+1} dx < +\infty,$$
for any $N > 0$ since $f(x) > 0 ~\forall x$.

Furthermore, I assume $$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x) = 0$$.

This means that:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 ~\exists N > 0: |x| >N \Rightarrow f(x) < \varepsilon.$$

Then:

$$f(x) < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \\
f(x) + 1 <  \varepsilon + 1 \Rightarrow \\
\frac{1}{f(x)+1} > \frac{1}{\varepsilon + 1} ~\forall x:|x| > N.
$$

This implies that:

$$\int_{N}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{f(x)+1} dx > \int_{N}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\varepsilon+1} dx = +\infty,$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-N} \frac{1}{f(x)+1} dx > \int_{-\infty}^{N} \frac{1}{\varepsilon+1} dx = +\infty.$$

Since:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{f(x)+1} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-N} \frac{1}{f(x)+1}dx + \int_{-N}^{N} \frac{1}{f(x)+1} dx + \int_{N}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{f(x)+1} dx$$

we can conclude that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{f(x)+1} dx $ diverges.

Comment: Your limit statement is false. For an example, let $T(x)=\begin{cases} 4x & x \in [0,1/2] \\ 2-4(x-1/2) & x \in [1/2,1] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ and $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty T(2^n(x-n))$. Then $f$ is integrable (in fact I think I chose the constants so that $\int f = 1$) but $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Ian I agree with you. But is $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty T(n^2(x-n))$ a distribution?

Comment: @vidyarthi you said this in your question, right?!?

Comment: @the_candyman By "distribution" do you mean that it is nonnegative and has integral $1$? Yes, after my tweaks I do believe I sorted out the factors of $2$ such that it does. The edited version consists of countably many triangles of height $2$ and width $2^{-n}$, so their area is $2^{-n}$ which sums to $1$.

Comment: @Ian maybe I'm wrong, but for distribution I mean a positive function, which integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is $1$ and the limit for $x \to \pm \infty$ is $0$.

Comment: The problem posed did not assert that $f(x)$ was always positive.

Comment: @MarkFischler I added now this as an hypothesis in my answer. I hope now it is sound. Thanks all for suggestions.

Comment: @the_candyman Why would you separately assume that $x \to \pm \infty$ is zero? This is not a standard usage in probability...

Comment: I think there is a problem of definition of "distribution" (see for example the answer of Alex. R)